can a planet have spiral arms?
Circumstellar disks can have spiral arms like a galaxy.
See https://www.nasa.gov/universe/spiral-arms-point-to-possible-planets-in-a-stars-dusty-disk/
What about circumplanetary disks? Can you have a planet with arms?

The formation mechanism of the "spiral arms" in a galaxy is different from those pictured in your link.
